# mongoosejs get _doc without loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question after performing a find() in mongoosejs.

Is there a better way of just getting the _doc-object without looping through the whole queryresult?

I'm searching for something like model.getDoc() but I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution by myself. Maybe it helps anyone:

```
var result = model.map(function(obj){
 return obj._doc;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only specific fields of documents use string with field names (separated by space) as a second parametr, if you want ommit specific fields use "-" before field name

```
Model.find({}, '_doc', function(){...});
```

But this return documents like this:

```
{
  _id: <object id>,
  _doc: <some data>
}
```

If you want ommit _id field:

```
Model.find({}, '_doc -_id', function(... {}))
```

Or alternative syntax:

```
Model.find({}).select('_doc -_id').exec()
```